# Tables and records missing in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Before the Xmas holidays, I was working on a database system, and since I've come back, I have tables missing in phpMyAdmin, and in the table I have left, i'm missing 15/40 records.

This was working fine before I left, and I didn't do anything before I logged back in.

I've run check database in cPanel, and this is what it's come up with:

```
tool_icarus is now being checked.
tool_icarus.areas
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.areas' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.books
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.books' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.employee                           OK
tool_icarus.levels
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.levels' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.presentation
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.presentation' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.seminar
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.seminar' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.test                               OK
tool_icarus.user_book
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.user_book' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.users
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.users' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
tool_icarus.webinar
Error    : Table 'tool_icarus.webinar' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
Check Complete
```

Please let me know what other data would be useful - it would suck to have to recreate these tables.

Comment: Was this open to the public?  Smells like [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)...

Comment: Nope, not open to the public
It hasn't been touched by my end (not 100% if hosting or anything has mucked something up)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like corruption of the database files. You may still be able to repair the tables. In PHPMyAdmin check the boxes next to the tables having problems. Then click `Repair Table` at the bottom of the table list.

If that doesn't work there are a couple different ways to try table repairs but you would then most likely need command line access on the database server.